# What is "auto-implemented" in C#?

Tags: c#

I need info about how "auto implemented" pertains to c# is and how and where I can use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest thing I can think of to what you're saying is [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Pre C# 3.0, if you wanted to write a public property, you would need to do the following:

```
private string _name;

public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

It has no logic and is a lot of boilerplate code really.

Now in C# 3.0, you can go:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The framework takes care of all the boilerplate stuff for you. You can mix and match different visibility levels of the getters / setters too, as long as you still obey the same rules as traditional properties.

Comment: wow,its a way to write codes simply,thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you mean properties, have a look here: [Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

For example:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    public double TotalPurchases { get; set; }
    public double MaxPurchases { get; private set; }

    public PurchaseOrder()
    {
        this.MaxPurchases = 10;
    }
}
```

`TotalPurchases` can be read or written to by any other public call.
`MaxPurchases` is set by only the current object but can be read by any other public call.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)?

From MSDN:

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. ... the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

Essentially, its simpler syntax for declaring properties that have simple getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You might have heard the term [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

This refers to properties that are written using a shorthand such as this:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Notice that the above is a lot quicker to write than this:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

Notice also that the auto-implemented version does not include any explicit declaration of a private field; this is because the field is automatically generated by the compiler, hence the term "Auto-Implemented."